# Ubuntu 18.10 and modify installed package - OpenMPI

Tags: apt, slurm, ubuntu-18.10

I've installed `openmpi-bin` (OpenMPI 3.1) on Ubuntu 18.10. I also run `slurm` on the same machine and would like to recompile or reconfigure my installation of OpenMPI to cope with Slurm-feature.

If one installs OpenMPI from source, there is a setting `--with-slurm` to be used.
How can I access or set the same setting during the installation of OpenMPI with the use of `apt` (and its install-service)?

Should I now uninstall the installed package, download source and build a new from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem and get a better understanding of how apt works. Simply put;
G

1. Get the source of the package via ''' apt-get source  ''' and cd to the dir with source.
2. Use the configuration-script (or likewise) to generate code for your requested settings.
3. Build  (make use of the make-commando, typically '''make all''')
4. Install (make use of '''make install'''

However for openmpi-bin there is some faulty configuration-script, yielding that the package-version is missing if one attemps to configure the checked out source. Instead, if one unpacks the tarball and make the requested settings to that source, then it works.

''' Update '''

It is still not functioning, using e.g. `mpiexec` I receive an error stating that some libs are missing. 
Not being able to sort out that problem I instead tried to build and the openmpi 
from debian build command (`debuild`).
I have taken the following steps:

1. `apt-get source openmpi-bin`
2. `dpkg-source -x openmpi-3.1.2-.dsc`
3. `cd to extracted dir`
4. `./configure --with-slurm`
5. `debuild -rfakeroot -us -uc -b -i` (as stated in the debian guidelines)

However this fails with the output of debuild-command stating the some files where not found and that the makefile exited with `error 1`.
More specific it is the compilation of `libopen-pal.so` that fails.

`dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2`.

Any idea as to why this might fail? Or if there is some log I could check to see why this fails.

Any help is much appreciated.